# Opening openoffice documents in vim

Tags: linux, vim

Is there any way to open openoffice.org documents inside vim, especially if it will preserve the formatting?

Ends up looking like:

`PK^C^D^T^@^@^H^@^@N¢^E=^Æ2^L'^@^@^@'^@^@^@^H^@^@^@mimetypeapplicationvnd.oasis.opendocument.textPK^C^D^T^@^H^H^H^@N¢^E=^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^K^@^@^@content.xmlµXÛnã6^P}ïW^H*Ð7Y±Ó^B^[7ö¢À¢@<81>^D(<90>´è+M<8e>,îòV<92>²­~}<87><94>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know for .sxw fies you change the file name to .zip, then unzip it then you'll be right to start looking in those files - maybe content.xml or something

Comment: Fascinating, that actually works! It complains of being malformed following recompilation, but that allows me to edit via vim, brilliant.

Answer (score 2):

There is an even shorter way instead of renaming to zip:

```
au BufReadCmd *.odt,*.ott,*.ods,*.ots,*.odp,*.otp,*.odg,*.otg call zip#Browse(expand("<amatch>"))
```

This will directly open the file as zip in vim

Answer (score 0):

No, I'm afraid not. Vim is a text editor, not a word processor. While Vim "understands" the syntax of a variety of text file formats, it doesn't understand native OpenOffice file formats.